# cannt get a record by the row number

Tags: sql, t-sql

i get an error with this query

```
select ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID) as num from T_TASK where ROW_NUMBER() = 5
```

and this one

```
select ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID) as num from T_TASK where num = 4
```

whats wrong with the queries?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT ID
FROM
(select ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID) as rownum from T_TASK) dr
WHERE rownum = 5
```

Answer (score 6):

Use a subquery:

```
SELECT ID
FROM (
    SELECT ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID) AS num
    FROM T_TASK
) T1 WHERE num = 5
```

Answer (score 0):

1 You can't use windows functions directly on the WHERE clause

2 The same is applied to alias name too